# Get character index from word index in a text

Tags: python, nltk

Given the index of a word in a text, I need to get the character index. 
For example, in the text below:

```
"The cat called other cats."
```

The index of word "cat" is 1. 
I need the index of the first character of cat i.e. c which will be 4.
I don't know if this is relevant but I am using python-nltk to get the words.
Right now the only way I can think of doing this is:

```
 - Get the first character, find the number of words in this piece of text
 - Get the first two characters, find the number of words in this piece of text
 - Get the first three characters, find the number of words in this piece of text
 Repeat until we get to the required word.
```

But this will be very inefficient.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. But I cannot just split on whitespaces to get words. I am using the TreebankWordTokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dict` here:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'\w+')
>>> text = "The cat called other cats."
>>> dic = { i :(m.start(0), m.group(0)) for i, m in enumerate(r.finditer(text))}
>>> dic
{0: (0, 'The'), 1: (4, 'cat'), 2: (8, 'called'), 3: (15, 'other'), 4: (21, 'cats')}
def char_index(char, word_ind):
    start, word = dic[word_ind]
    ind = word.find(char)
    if ind != -1:
        return start + ind
...     
>>> char_index('c',1)
4
>>> char_index('c',2)
8
>>> char_index('c',3)
>>> char_index('c',4)
21
```

Comment: I think you are going one step further than what the OP is asking for.  I don't **think** OP wants to find the specific character index given a word index, but rather the first character index each time.  But, a general solution like this is probably better anyway.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def char_index(sentence, word_index):
    sentence = re.split('(\s)',sentence) #Parentheses keep split characters
    return len(''.join(sentence[:word_index*2]))
```

---

```
>>> s = 'The die has been cast'
>>> char_index(s,3)    #'been' has index 3 in the list of words
12
>>> s[12]
'b'
>>>
```

Comment: What happens when the first character of the word, in this example 'b', is used earlier in the sentence.

Comment: That's fine as long as 'been' wasn't used earlier in the sentence

Comment: ah, right, you are searching for the word.  So, what happens when the target word is used earlier in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()`

```
>>> def obt(phrase, indx):
...     word = phrase.split()[indx]
...     e = list(enumerate(phrase))
...     for i, j in e:
...             if j == word[0] and ''.join(x for y, x in e[i:i+len(word)]) == word:
...                     return i
... 
>>> obt("The cat called other cats.", 1)
4
```

Comment: This is wrong, if the first character of the word appears earlier in the sentence, it returns that index.

Comment: @JeremyBentham I've noticed. I'm fixing :)